# IBM App Connect Enterprise - Pass Path Param to Rest Request Node

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

In IBM App Connect Enterprise REST API project, how can I pass path a parameter to a REST Request Node?

I can set a query parameter in a compute node using ESQL like

`SET InputLocalEnvironment.Destination.REST.Request.Parameters.id = 'abc'.`

The API works without an issue. But If I do the same thing for a path parameter the values are not getting passed. As a work around I set the value to an Environment variable in a compute node and get it via XPATH in the Rest Request Node properties.

Is there a similar way to set the path parameter in ESQL just like the query parameter?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So a bit surprised that InputLocalEnvironment is working for you.

For a RESTRequest node the URL is built up from BaseURL and Operation values, the Parameters option you've already found. The code below illustrates some of the values outlined in [Environment Variables with Rest Nodes](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTTDS_11.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bz90950_.html) that can be used to override the behaviour of REST nodes. The link also describes values that are set after a REST Node has done its thing.

```
SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.REST.Request.BaseURL = 'https://my-prod-server.ibm.com/customerdb/v1';
SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.REST.Request.Operation = 'updateCustomerByID';
SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.REST.Request.Parameters.max = 10;
SET OutputLocalEnvironment.Destination.REST.Request.Parameters.filter = 'Fred Bloggs';
```

Remember to configure the **Compute** Node to have a **Compute Mode** of **LocalEnvironment And Message** otherwise your settings are not going to be passed on to the subsequent RESTRequest node.

Comment: Thanks a lot TJA, your explanation helped and the changed code worked, Yes you are correct, how InputLocalEnvironment.Destination.REST.Request.Parameters worked!